# Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories. while using in STS

Tags: maven, maven-nar-plugin

I am able to create Spring Boot Starter Project and Maven Web Project from the STS, but somehow unable to create the **maven-archetype-quickstart** project in eclipse, its giving me below error

[image]

[image]

In my project, I am using cacert file and custom setting.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by simply deleting the .m2 folder and create maven project from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
maven clean install -U
```

as your repository is cached so try to flush the cache using -U

Comment: Error is  coming when I am creating Maven Project from STS/Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

After facing the same issue and going through the message several times - I found that in the local repository i.e. .m2, under the location - org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.1 - we found the error in the file - 'm2e-lastUpdated.properties' as '*@default-central-https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1551236380266
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=**Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org***'

So my Eclipse was not able to download the required JARS may be cause it is behind the firewall and in that case - Place the '**maven-archetype-quickstart-1.1.jar**' and '**maven-archetype-quickstart-1.1.pom**' in your local repo at the location - '**org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.1**' using the link - [JARS_POM](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.1/) and then follow the same step to create the maven Project.

Better solution is to use proxy through 'setting.xml' file of Maven to bypass the firewall to download Maven plugins and jars.

You should also check if the maven archetype catalog to eclipse is configured properly.